# How to update tkinter scrollbar size for canvas size

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I want to have a vertical and horizontal scroll bar on the window that automatically updates for the size of the canvas. I got it partly there, and right now the code creates extra scroll bars for each update and the horizontal scroll bar doesn't span the length of the whole canvas. Here is a sample I created to illustrate this:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk



root = tkinter.Tk()
root.state("zoomed")
bigframe = tkinter.Frame(root)
bigframe.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(bigframe)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)
scrollbarv = ttk.Scrollbar(bigframe, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollbarh = ttk.Scrollbar(bigframe, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
scrollbarv.pack(side="right", fill="y")
scrollbarh.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbarv.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarh.set)
canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
mainframe = tkinter.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=mainframe, anchor="nw")


i = 1
text = "Hello World! "
def click():
    global i
    global text
    for t in range(10):
        i += 1
        text += "Hello World! "
        tkinter.Label(mainframe, text=text).pack()
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(bigframe, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

button = tkinter.Button(mainframe, text="Click me!", command=click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is what happens when I click the button 4 times: [image]

I believe the horizontal scrollbar being small is due to me saying `canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)`, but if I say `side="top` then the vertical scroll bars don't span the height of the canvas.
Is there some specific piece of code that is causing the multiple scrollbars issue or the horizontal bar issue? And if so, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to destroy the old scrollbar before you add a new one. Just add scrollbar.destroy() to your click function, like I did below:

```
def click():
    global i
    global text
    for t in range(10):
        i += 1
        text += "Hello World! "
        tkinter.Label(mainframe, text=text).pack()
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(bigframe, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.destroy()
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
```

I made the following changes to your code. At first it doesn't work, however if I resize the window it works perfectly.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk



root = tkinter.Tk()
root.state("zoomed")
bigframe = tkinter.Frame(root)
bigframe.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(bigframe)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)
scrollbarv = ttk.Scrollbar(bigframe, orient="vertical", 
command=canvas.yview)
scrollbarh = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", 
command=canvas.xview)
scrollbarv.pack(side="right", fill="y")
scrollbarh.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbarv.set, 
xscrollcommand=scrollbarh.set)
canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: 
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
mainframe = tkinter.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=mainframe, anchor="nw")


i = 1
text = "Hello World! "

def updateScrollRegion():
    canvas.update_idletasks()
    canvas.config(scrollregion=mainframe.bbox())

def click():
    global i, scrollbarv, text
    for t in range(10):
        i += 1
        text += "Hello World! "
        tkinter.Label(mainframe, text=text).pack()

button = tkinter.Button(mainframe, text="Click me!", command=click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I try that, the scroll bar becomes gray and it doesn't scroll. Thanks for the suggestion though. Do you know if some lines need to be moved around in order for it to work with this method?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Using you idea, I was able to fix it and remove the multiple bars issue by messing around with some global variables

Comment: Oh that's great, no problem. Can you please post the working code, I would like to see it.

Comment: I used your first suggestion and moved the destroy command above the ttk.Scrollbar command, and I put global scrollbar at the top of the function. I can try remaking the code if you would like me to but I only made that as an example to illustrate my problem and it is pretty different in my main program code.

Comment: One other thing I looked into is https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/2841b7b640bba48928200ff979204115, which is a double scrollbar frame by novel-yet-trivial and it works beautifully while simplifying the process